# How to get a file's Media Created date using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, how do I extract the `Media Created` date attribute value shown here in file explorer?

[image]

If possible I'd like to do this for all files in a given directory too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the guidance on the [enumerate file properties in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420055/enumerate-file-properties-in-powershell) post, I've created a variation of this PowerShell logic and put it into a couple scripts to assist with the task.

I've included looping logic, some parsing and conditional logic, and logic that sets the [variable data types](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html) to assist with getting the final desired value.

> **Note:** I've put in conditional logic to help omit null values from the output.

### PowerShell

Set `$flPath`to the full path and file name of a file. Set `$attrName` to the attribute name of the metadata property to get its value (*e.g. the datetime of "Media Created"*).

```
$flPath = "M:\Fortune500\Millionaires Club.mov";
$attrName = "media created"

$path = $flPath;
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application;
$folder = Split-Path $path;
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf;
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder);
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file);

$a = 0..500 | % { Process { $x = '{0} = {1}' -f $_, $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_); If ( $x.split("=")[1].Trim() ) { $x } } };
[int]$num = $a | % { Process { If ($_ -like "*$attrName*") { $_.Split("=")[0].trim() } } };
$mCreated = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $num);
$mCreated;
```

**Output Example**

```
12/‎31/‎2020 ‏‎7:55 PM
```

---

### PowerShell (all files in a directory)

Set `$fldPath` to the directory the files are in, set `$flExt` to the dot extension of the file types to search, and set `$attrName` to the attribute name of the metadata property to get its value.

```
$fldPath = "M:\Fortune500";
$flExt = ".mov";
$attrName = "media created"

(Get-ChildItem -Path "$fldPath\*" -Include "*$flExt").FullName | % { 
    $path = $_
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application;
    $folder = Split-Path $path;
    $file = Split-Path $path -Leaf;
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder);
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file);

    $a = 0..500 | % { Process { $x = '{0} = {1}' -f $_, $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_); If ( $x.split("=")[1].Trim() ) { $x } } };
    [int]$num = $a | % { Process { If ($_ -like "*$attrName*") { $_.Split("=")[0].trim() } } };
    $mCreated = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $num);
    $mCreated;
};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Folder.GetDetailsOf method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)

Comment: @LCIII ... I assume putting all files in a folder recursively or not in a loop and then having the `$path` variable iterated accordingly per the values set is just a trivial matter you are capable of getting completed. If not though and you require assist with that part, I'll be happy to help you there too and amend to my answer.

Comment: @LCIII After rereading your question, I noticed you did seek a solution for all files in a given folder so I went ahead and added that to the my answer. Happy to clarify further if needed but assume you got it from here. If you run into any issues though, just reply here and I will help resolve. If you have special named files, you might try using `-LiteralPath` parameter with `Get-ChildItem` rather than just `-Path`. Let me know what I can do to help get your problem fully resolve so you can do what you need.

Comment: This was it! And for what it's worth, the `Media Created` attribute was 208 for me. Would it ever not be 208? Could I get by with `$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 208);`?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't know the answer though. Since you know what the name will be though, that may be better anyway in case it is ever any different. Otherwise might be able to answer that if you cannot figure it out though so maybe another question with your logic example and then ask the question so they know what you are working with. I do this when I ask questions, I open another question about further questions on that answer or new logic used. I do that more on StackOverflow though personally and for more SQL and Python related questions just for an example.

Comment: [It looks like it should always be 208](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/Extract-exif-data-from-image-with-Power-Automate-Desktop/m-p/1902072/highlight/true#M20733) but going down the rabbit hole trying to *prove* it is [difficult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-document-datecreated). The sparse docs that do exist say it's defined in `Propkey.h`, though if you look through that for `208` (or `0xD0`) it's not a fun time..

Answer (score 2):

Here is some (untested) example code:

```
$FilePath = 'C:\Videos\Test.mp4'
$Folder = Split-Path -Parent -Path $FilePath
$File = Split-Path -Leaf -Path $FilePath
$Shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$ShellFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($Folder)
$ShellFile = $ShellFolder.ParseName($File)

Write-Host $ShellFile.ExtendedProperty("System.Media.Duration")
```

References:

- [ShellFolderItem.ExtendedProperty method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty)
- [Predefined Property Set Format Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/predefined-property-set-format-identifiers)

Comment: For some reason `$ShellFolder` is returning null. So when I run `$ShellFile = $ShellFolder.ParseName($File)` it throws a null reference error. `$Folder` in this case is `.`

Comment: The operations above are on the path as a string, so don't work on `.`. You need to convert it to full path by, for example: `$FullPath = Resolve-Path $FilePath`.

Answer (score 0):

Works a treat and much simpler than the other answer.

To get the creation date, use:

```
Write-Host $ShellFile.ExtendedProperty("System.Media.**DateEncoded**")
```

...rather than `System.Media.Duration` as shown in the example.